# No FQDN access to local server from local network, only from outside

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04

Ubuntu 14.04 set up with several services (media server, cloud backup server, etc) on FQDN updated with no-ip. The server is set up behind a ZyXEL router and is not a gateway or DHCP server, just a node on the network. I am able to access the services via the FQDN from the public side, but only by local IP from the private side.

This server used to be set up as gateway/firewall and DHCP for the internal network and this all worked fine, now with the new setup, it doesn't.

The network is set up as follows:

```
+Modem
   +Router
      +Switch
         +Wireless AP
         +Ubuntu server
         +Other wired devices
```

I've tried flushing my iptables thinking there was something there, but that hasn't done it. Any thoughts as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you run `dig your-server-public-fqdn` and see whether the returned IP matches the one that you expect?

Comment: The `;; ANSWER SECTION:` shows the FQDN with the external IP address of my modem, and that is correct. There is more information below that, Query time, SERVER, WHEN, MSG, and SERVER returns 192.168.0.1 which is the router, and the server is on 192.168.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router sucks and doesn't do NAT Loopback (a.k.a. hairpin NAT). Get a better router or load firmware on it that doesn't suck and can do NAT Loopback.

Comment: It is a ZyXEL FR1000Z, just what CenturyLink sold me. I managed to get into the cli of the router and found this in its ifconfig: 

`lo        Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:27915 (27.2 KiB)  TX bytes:27915 (27.2 KiB)` That looks like loopback is on, but just not doing much???

Comment: That's a completely different type of loopback, not NAT loopback.